# Как создать textbox для сайта

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток!  Хочу сделать поле для ввода текста, но только не стандартное (квадратное), а приличного вида с закругленными краями и со своей цветовой гаммой.  Стандартный HTML код я знаю    `<form> <input type="text"> </form>` , а как его украсить так и не понял. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как реализовать подобное?

Comment: гуглите css. например: "css закругленный бордер"

Comment: Рекомендую начать погружение в таинства разметки с учебника русского языка.

Answer (score 2):

сss в помощь.

Например вот так (вставь в область head)

```
<style>
input[type="text"] {
width: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не очень хочется заморачиваться с `css`, попробуйте взять [стили из css-фреймворка bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation), если я правильно понял что вам нужно